# Rails 4.1.5 update error: UnsatisfiableDependencyError

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I got the below error when doing a gem update.

```
Updating installed gems
Updating rails
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::UnsatisfiableDependencyError)
    Unable to resolve dependency: user requested 'rails (= 4.1.5)'
```

This is what I have after `gem list | grep rails`

```
coffee-rails (4.0.1, 4.0.0)
jquery-rails (3.1.1, 3.0.4)
rails (4.1.4, 4.0.0)
sass-rails (4.0.3, 4.0.0)
sprockets-rails (2.1.3, 2.0.1, 2.0.0)
```

How can I resolve the error?

Comment: Try it now. I was having this issue as well, but now it's gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think rubygems.org is out of sync, it should fix itself within an hour.

More info on how rubygems.org works: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4_TqAMWbzfw